# Removing `+0000` from the Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe of tweets

```
# Print only one column
uchicago_tweets_pd_df.created_at.head(1)
```

Output:

```
0    Thu Jun 22 14:16:34 +0000 2017
Name: created_at, dtype: object
```

What is the best and correct way to remove it? Just drop or convert into something else for further splitting into different columns?

Comment: you can reformat the datetime object to another format that excludes `+0000`. something along the lines of `strftime`

Comment: if you have it as string then you can use string function like `replace("+0000", "")` but I would rather convert it to `datetime` and later keep it as is (without bothering `+0000`) because it can be more useful to split to other columns or  to compare times.